# Avoid unnecessary crawling of ad landing URLs by disallowing query string with robots.txt

Tags: seo, robots.txt, google-ads

Will the following configuration allow me to run an Ads campaign for products with the `?string` parameter in the URL?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*?string

User-agent: AdsBot-Google
Allow: /

User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Allow: /

User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Allow: /
```

I want to avoid unnecessary crawling robots on the filter pages. Is there a configuration of the robots.txt file that will allow campaigns on filter subpages while limiting access to them for the main "Googlebot"?

Answer (score 1):

Your `robots.txt` syntax is correct.  That will disallow bots that understand wildcards (including Googlebot and Bingbot) from crawling your parameters while allowing AdSense to run on those URLs.

The alternative is to use [canonical tags](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls#rel-canonical-link-method) in your pages.  That way those ad landing query strings will be removed from URLs that Google indexes and you don't have to (and shouldn't try to) limit crawling with `robots.txt`.